# How can I call the svn.client.svn_client_list2 with python SVN API SWIG bindings?

Tags: python

## The question

How do I call [`svn_client_list2`](http://svn.collab.net/svn-doxygen/group__List.html#ga1) C API function from python via SVN API SWIG bindings?

## Problem description

I can find that function from the `svn.client` module, but **calling it is the problem**, because the callback function it uses is a typedef [`svn_client_list_func_t`](http://svn.collab.net/svn-doxygen/group__List.html#ga0) and I don't know how to use that typedef in python.

Although I can find a class for it from `svn.client.svn_client_list_func_t` along with `svn.client.svn_client_list_func_tPtr`, but I can't find an example of how to use it.

### Incorrect usage of svn.client.svn_client_list2

If you call the `svn.client.svn_client_list2` function with a normal python function as callback parameter it gives you an error.

```
import svn.core, svn.client

path = svn.core.svn_path_canonicalize("/path/to/a/working_copy/")
pool = svn.core.Pool()
ctx = svn.client.svn_client_create_context(pool)
revision = svn.core.svn_opt_revision_t()
SVN_DIRENT_ALL = 0xffffffffl
def _handle_list(path, dirent, abs_path, pool):
  print(path, dirent, abs_path, pool)

svn.client.svn_client_list2(path,
                            revision,
                            revision,
                            svn.core.svn_depth_infinity,
                            SVN_DIRENT_ALL,
                            True,
                            _handle_list,
                            ctx,
                            pool)
```

`TypeError: argument number 7: a 'svn_client_list_func_t *' is expected, 'function(<function _handle_list at 0x01365270>)' is received`

### Incorrect usage of svn.client.svn_client_list_func_t

Trying to initialize the `svn.client.svn_client_list_func_t` will result to an exception.

```
callback_function = svn.client.svn_client_list_func_t()
```

`RuntimeError: No constructor defined`

Ideas how I can proceed?

Comment: you're not actually using `svn_client_list2`, are you?

Comment: I actually am, because that list2 is an alias, but I could edit it to use the one I am asking about... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can't really do this at the moment. When I dug into bit into the SWIG bindings code and documentation it says that when you're using target language functions as  the callback function, you need a typemap for it as it says in the [SWIG documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIG.html#SWIG_nn30):

> Although SWIG does not normally allow callback functions to be written in the target language, this can be accomplished with the use of typemaps and other advanced SWIG features.

It looked like it was missing for Python...